# Query id / elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

we're batteling the query id for a few days now but it doesn't seem to work. We want queries like "all posts in the last seven days" "all posts older than seven days but younger than 30" and "all posts older than 30 days". We started out with a few tries but nothing really changes.

Last effort was this one:

```
    function zevendagen($args, $filter){

    $args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
       'key' => '_my_custom_field',
       'type' => 'DATE',
       'compare' => 'after',
       'value' => array('2022-10-05')
         ),
    );

    return $args;
    }
    add_action( 'elementor/query/{$query_id}', 'zevendagen' );
```

Do you know why nothing is happening? We created this using the Code Snippets plugin but ended functions.php as well

We use Elementor in this project, we can enter a query id there and then it has to do something with it. Not. Wordpress folders do contain a elementor folder, no query folder though

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `{$query_id}` to the query id value you gave in the loop/post widget.